# Safari is saying FormData.entries() is not a function

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, safari

I have an ajax function that posts an image, which works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. Safari and iOS Safari both balk at it, though.

I'm creating and appending the value like this:

```
var ajaxImage = new FormData();
ajaxImage.append('file-0', $('.some-file-input')[0].files[0]);
```

I then call this image later, using `ajaxImage.entries()` to init the iterator for the `FormData` object, so that I can perform a validation on it. However, in Safari `ajaxImage.entries()` throws an `entries is not a function` TypeError.

I guess I could just do the validation before getting to this point as a workaround, but now it's bugging me so I wanted to see if anyone could shed some light on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Safari doesn't support this part of the specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility, specifically the entries method.

I haven't tried it myself, but perhaps a polyfill like this one: https://github.com/francois2metz/html5-formdata might work?

But yes, you might be right -- doing validation before that point might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and for the tip on the FormDate polyfill, which could be useful in the future. I think you're right, though, I'll just do my validations before they're inside the FormData, circumventing the Safari issue. That's a bummer, but good to know about! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by conditionally (if Safari is the browser) iterating through the **elements** property of the **form**.  For all other browser, my wrapper just iterates through **FormData entries()**.  The end result of my function, in either case, is a simple javascript object (JSON) which amounts to name/value pairs.  That object can be passed directly to the **data** property of the JQuery **ajax** function (with **contentType** and **processData** not specified).

```
function FormDataNameValuePairs(FormName)
{
  var FormDaytaObject={};
  var FormElement=$('#'+FormName).get(0);

  if (IsSafariBrowser())
  {
    var FormElementCollection=FormElement.elements;
    //console.log('namedItem='+FormElementCollection.namedItem('KEY'));
    var JQEle,EleType;
    for (ele=0; (ele < FormElementCollection.length); ele++)
    {
      JQEle=$(FormElementCollection.item(ele));
      EleType=JQEle.attr('type');

      // https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData/blob/master/FormData.js
      if ((! JQEle.attr('name')) ||
          (((EleType == 'checkbox') || (EleType == 'radio')) &&
           (! JQEle.prop('checked'))))
        continue;
      FormDaytaObject[JQEle.attr('name')]=JQEle.val();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    var FormDayta=new FormData(FormElement);
    for (var fld of FormDayta.entries())
      FormDaytaObject[fld[0]]=fld[1];
  }

  return FormDaytaObject;
}
```

where IsSafariBrowser() is implemented by whatever your favorite method is, but I chose this:

```
function IsSafariBrowser()
{
  var VendorName=window.navigator.vendor;
  return ((VendorName.indexOf('Apple') > -1) &&
          (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') > -1));
}
```

Example usage with an ajax call:

```
var FormDaytaObject=FormDataNameValuePairs('FiltersForm');

$.ajax({url: 'AJAXDoSomethingWithFilters/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: FormDaytaObject,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data)
                 {
                   console.log('AJAXDoSomethingWithFilters success:'+data);
                 },
        error: function(JQXhr,Status,Err)
               {
                 console.log('AJAXDoSomethingWithFilters error:'+Err);
               }
       });
```